# iTunes Smart Playlists: don't include songs that I recently skipped

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist

In the iTunes 12.7.2.60, I'm trying to create a Smart Playlist with the songs that I didn't listen to in a while. This playlist should not include songs that I skipped recently. My current rules look like the following (see the screenshot):
[image]

However, the iTunes still adds songs that I skipped. How can I make it to exclude songs that I skipped recently?

Answer (score 1):

The rules look correct.  The problem may be in what YOU consider a skip versus what iTunes/iOS considers a skip.  There's varying reports that a skip in the first 3 seconds doesn't get counted, a skip in the last 10 seconds doesn't get counted, etc.

Maybe the best thing to do is this:

Create another smart playlist RecentlySkipped with one rule: Last Skipped IS IN THE LAST 1 days.

Then alter your existing playlist by replacing the "last skipped" rule with "Playlist IS NOT RecentlySkipped".

You can then play around with playing tracks and skipping them at various times - in the first 2 seconds, in the first 10 seconds, in the first 15 seconds, in the last 15 seconds, etc.  Then check the RecentlySkipped playlist to see which ones got added to it and which ones didn't.

Also, the play and skip count logic has been changed from release to release in the past.  So it's possible, for example, that what counted as a skip in iTunes 12.6 is not counted as a skip in iTunes 12.7 or vice versa.

Also, in older versions of iTunes you could reset play count independently of resetting skip count.  More recent versions reset both counts whether you want them both reset or not.